# mocking functions from base class

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a base class where I connect to a mongodb collection and read a date value from an hdfs file, then delete values that are older compared to the value read from this hdfs file. I have some problems with unittesting, so:

In the child class I have the following:

```py
def remove_old_sources(self):
    input_date = self.get_date_from_input()
    mongo_collection = self.connect_to_collection(db, collection)
    deleted_files_count = self.delete_stale_documents(mongo_collection, input_date)
```

all the functions that are called above comes from the base class. My question is how can I mock them in the following way:

the input_date with a `datetime` object and the mongo_collection with `Collection` that comes from mongomock such as:

```
mocked_collection = mongomock.MongoClient().db.collection
mocked_collection.insert_many([
    {'_id': '1', 'time': datetime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)},
    {'_id': '2', 'time': datetime(2015, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)},
    {'_id': '3', 'time': datetime(2020, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)},
    {'_id': '4', 'time': datetime(2030, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)},
    {'_id': '5', 'time': datetime(2040, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)},
])
```

This `mongomock` created a local mongodb in memory if I understood it correctly.

I tried:

```
@mock.patch("path_to_base_class.get_date_from_input")
@mock.patch("path_to_base_class.connect_to_collection")
def test_remove_old_docs(connect_mock, date_mock)
```

and then initialize the child class and run `remove_old_sources` but the mock objects are `MagicMock` objects like this, I'm not sure how to overwrite them with what I mentioned above. Also tried with a context manager `with mock.patch(BaseClass, "function_name", mocked_stuff)` and then initialize the `Child` class but it doesn't work like this.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You get `MagicMock` objects because that's the standard object type produced when you call a mocked object. You can always replace their `return_value` attribute if you want something else passed on.

However, you don't need to mock your mongo collection, your code never touches any of that data anyway.

Your code makes 3 calls:

```
    input_date = self.get_date_from_input()
    mongo_collection = self.connect_to_collection(db, collection)
    deleted_files_count = self.delete_stale_documents(mongo_collection, input_date)
```

From the first two calls, the code sets two local variables, `input_date` and `mongo_collection`, that are then passed to a 3rd method, `self.delete_stale_documents()`.

If your goal is to verify that the code correctly passes those two arguments on to the 3rd method, then all you have to do is mock out the 3 methods and verify that the return value of the first 2 is passed to the 3rd:

```
@mock.patch("path_to_base_class.delete_stale_documents")
@mock.patch("path_to_base_class.connect_to_collection")
@mock.patch("path_to_base_class.get_date_from_input")
def test_remove_old_docs(date_mock, connect_mock, delete_mock):
    input_date_mock = date_mock.return_value  # a specific MagicMock object
    collection_mock = connect_mock.return_value  # another specific MagicMock object

    # call code-under-test here

    delete_mock.assert_called_with(collection_mock, input_date_mock)
```

The `delete_mock.assert_called_with()` would pass only if the result of the  `connect_mock()` and `date_mock()` calls were used to call `delete_mock()`.

If your test is more involved, with, say, the return value of `self.delete_stale_documents()`, you can set a specific value as the return value for that call by setting `.return_value` before the test:

```
    delete_mock.return_value = 42
```

Now, `deleted_files_count` will be set to `42`, and you can make further assertions if your code handled that value correctly.